# Fuseki WebServer with Node.js . Cant get single elements only whole graph

Tags: javascript, node.js, webserver, sparql, fuseki

So we are supposed to set up an WebServer with Fuseki and Nodejs. 
I defined the classes with the following  OWL Ontology and loaded it up to the Fuseki server.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
         xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
         xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
         xmlns:ns0="http://localhost:3000/data#">

  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#message">
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>

  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#firstname">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#ObjectProperty"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>

  <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#lastname">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#ObjectProperty"/>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>

  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#linkeddata">
    <rdfs:comment>The class of all data types.</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:label>The data type</rdfs:label>
  </owl:Class>

  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#users">
    <rdfs:comment>Users that post Tweets.</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:label>Users</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://localhost:3000/data#linkeddata"/>
  </owl:Class>

  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#tweets">
    <rdfs:comment>Tweets contain messages of Users.</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:label>Tweets</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="http://localhost:3000/data#linkeddata"/>
  </owl:Class>

  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#tweetedby">
  </owl:ObjectProperty>

  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#1234">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://localhost:3000/data#tweets"/>
    <ns0:message>blablubbtweet</ns0:message>
    <ns0:tweetedby>
      <ns0:users rdf:about="http://localhost:3000/data#2345">
        <ns0:firstname>Manuel</ns0:firstname>
        <ns0:lastname>Neuer</ns0:lastname>
      </ns0:users>
    </ns0:tweetedby>

  </rdf:Description>

</rdf:RDF>
```

I hope you can read it. It works however. I can then view the classes directly by typing this into Fuseki web interface. With "'2345" for example being the User Manuel Neuer.

```
SELECT * WHERE { GRAPH ?g { <http://localhost:3000/data#2345> ?p ?o}}
```

However, in my Node.js application, I somehow am only able to get the whole graph, and I dont know why. 
The following is the Nodejs code :

I think the error must be at

```
function sparql_GET_Data_Element (URIhash) {

  postData =
    ` describe <http://localhost:3030/data#` + URIhash + `>`
```

Its like he would always `describe http:/localhost:3030/data#` and never take the `urihash`. I would be delighted about every tip. Thanks alot. I test it by sending `GET` requests with Insomnia Rest Api. 
`http://localhost:3030/data#2345` this get request generates the same whole graph as `http://localhost:3030/data#users`.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const app_port = 3000
const apache_fuseki_persistence_url = 'http://localhost:3030'
const http = require('http');

const rdf_url_prefix_tag = 'PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>'
const rdff_url_prefix_tag = 'PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>'

const SPARQL_GET_ALL_CLASSES = function (){
  postData =
  `
  prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
  prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

  SELECT DISTINCT ?class ?label ?description
  WHERE {
    ?class a owl:Class.
    OPTIONAL { ?class rdfs:label ?label}
    OPTIONAL { ?class rdfs:comment ?description}
  }
  `
  const options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 3030,
    path: '/data/query',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/sparql-results+json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/sparql-query'
    }
  }

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var req = http.request( options, function(res) {
        // reject on bad status
        if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
            return reject(new Error('statusCode=' + res.statusCode));
        }
        var data = {};
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
          data = chunk;
        });
        // resolve on end
        res.on('end', function() {
          resolve(JSON.parse(data));
        });
      });

      // reject on request error
      req.on('error', function(err) {
          // This is not a "Second reject", just a different sort of failure
          reject(err);
      });
      if (postData) {
          req.write(postData);
      }
      // IMPORTANT
      req.end();
  });
}



function sparql_GET_Data_Element (URIhash) {

  postData =
    ` describe <http://localhost:3030/data#` + URIhash + `>`

  const options = {
    hostname: 'localhost',
    port: 3030,
    path: '/data/query',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/ld+json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/sparql-query'
    }
  }

  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var req = http.request( options, function(res) {
        // reject on bad status
        if (res.statusCode < 200 || res.statusCode >= 300) {
          reject(new Error('statusCode=' + res.statusCode));
        }
        var data = [];
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
          data.push(chunk);
        });
        // resolve on end
        res.on('end', function() {
          resolve(JSON.parse(data[0]));
        });
      });

      // reject on request error
      req.on('error', function(err) {
          // This is not a "Second reject", just a different sort of failure
          reject(err);
      });
      if (postData) {
          req.write(postData);
      }
      // IMPORTANT
      req.end();
  });
}

function sparql_CREATE_NEW_CLASS(new_rdfs_class){

}

// var promiseB = promiseA.then(function(result) {
//   // do something with result
// });

function rdfs_class_exists (requested_class){
  return SPARQL_GET_ALL_CLASSES().then(result => {
    let found_class = false;
    result.results.bindings.forEach(element => {
      if (element.class.value == 'http://localhost:3000/data#'+requested_class) {
        found_class = true;
      }
    })
    return found_class;
  });
}

app.get('*', function(req, res, next){
  path_elements = req.path.split('#');
  var requested_class = path_elements[1];

  rdfs_class_exists(requested_class).then((RDFS_Class_found) => {
    if (RDFS_Class_found){
      if(path_elements.length > 3){
        sparql_GET_Data_Element(path_elements[3]).then(result => {
          console.log('result: ' + result);
          res.send(result);
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          res.send(error);
        })
      } else {
        sparql_GET_Data_Element(path_elements[1]).then(result => {
          console.log('result: ' + result);
          var ele = sparql_GET_Data_element(path_elements[1]);
            res.send(ele);
      //    res.send(result);
        }).catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          res.send(error);
        })
      }

    } else res.status(400).send("RDFS Class not Found");
  });
})

app.post('*', function(req, res, next){
next();

})

app.delete('*', function(req, res, next){
  next();
})

app.put('*', function(req, res, next){
  next();
})

app.all('*', function (req, res, next){
  res.status(400).send('No Elements found');
})

/**
 * Die API wartet auf Requests am Port 3000.
 * Wird sie per Node gitlokal gestartet läuft sie unter http://localhost:3000/
 */
app.listen(app_port, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Comment: Note that HTTP `GET http://localhost:3030/data#2345` usually doesn't send the fragment identifier (`#2345`) to the server -- and even if your client tool includes it, the server is required to ignore it! The interpretation of the fragment identifier is left to the client app, and is based on the media type of the file it gets back. (This is all very different from SPARQL `DESCRIBE <http://localhost:3030/data#2345>`.)

Comment: Thank you TallTed I will look into it.

Comment: So I figured out that I can get it via href. But just for my understanding, when I give the hash element (2345) to my function sparql_get_data_element, and change the Sparql request to the following . 
"'SELECT * WHERE { GRAPH ?g { <http://localhost:3000/data#'+urihash+'> ?p ?o}}'"
It should work ? Because I just get the same graph like before. While in Fuseki Web Interface this request is exactlyy what Id want ... Do I need to set up my ontolog anew ? Maybe you could clear up some greater misunderstandings....Thank you and good night !

Comment: what means you get the "same graph"? when you're doing `SELECT * WHERE { GRAPH ?g { <localhost:3000/data#'+urihash+'> ?p ?o}}` ? And Fuseki is a SPARQL server over HTTP and not a Linked data client, I don't think that a `GET` request with `http://localhost:3030/data#2345` will work.

Comment: I think you need to edit your question to include the progress you've made, and to be more explicit about what you're doing now, and the results you're now getting -- because "I just get the same graph like [when I did the GET]" doesn't make sense in talking about executing a SPARQL query.